# Understanding tensorflow calculation of MSE for output vector of N dimensions

Tags: measurement-error, mse

Here is the code example with variable names guiding the process:

```
const yTrue = tf.tensor2d([[0, 1], [3, 4]]);
const yPred = tf.tensor2d([[0, 1], [-3, -4]]);
const mse = tf.metrics.meanSquaredError(yTrue, yPred);
mse.print(); // [0, 50]
```

The whole point of the code is to show the result, which is `[0, 50]` and try to understand why it is so.

The squared error is:

$$ (Y_T -Y_P)^2 $$

squaring the differences between true values and predicted.

I am assume that, if each **Y** is a vector instead, we could think of it as a point in space (say with 2 coordinates) and the error is an average of those errors

So L would be of the length of the vector. For example, in this case, it would give

$$ \frac{1}{L} (\vec{Y_T} -\vec{Y_P}) \cdot (\vec{Y_T} -\vec{Y_P}) $$

Is this idea correct? I can not find it by searches or maybe do not know the exact term for it, or it is just wrong.

I still do not get how the code outputs `[0,50]` as the output and not `25`.